# why is always this error Undefined variable $question

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I try to give the data from database to the blade.php.

The controller:

```
class DataController extends Controller
{
// sql query from datebase
public  function  question_number()
{
    $questions =  DB::table('questions')->sum('id');

    return  view('/statistics',['question'  =>  $questions ]);
}


public  function  group_number()
{
    $groups =  DB::table('groups')->sum('id');

    return  view('/statistics', ['group'  =>  $groups ]);
}

}
```

in there I have define the value `$question` and `$group`

and in Blade.php I have try to use this value:

```
<div>Die Anzahl von Fragen</div>
                    <p> {{ $question }} </p>
                    <div>Die Anzahl von Gruppen</div>
                    <p> {{ $group }} </p>
```

in route

```
Route::get('/statistics', 'DataController@question_number');
Route::get('/statistics', 'DataController@group_number');
```

but the error is always

> Undefined variable $question

What did I miss? And what should I do?

Comment: To both views you only pass one variable but in your view you reference both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to send 2 variables to one view, I think. To do this you don't need 2 `routes` and 2 `controllers`. In fact you CAN'T do that.

Route File:

```
Route::get('/statistics', 'DataController@question_number');
```

Controller:

```
class DataController extends Controller
{
    // sql query from datebase
    public  function  question_number()
    {
        $questions =  DB::table('questions')->sum('id');
        $groups =  DB::table('groups')->sum('id');

        return  view('/statistics',['question'  =>  $questions , 'group' => $groups]);
    }     
}
```

View (without change):

```
<div>Die Anzahl von Fragen</div>
                    <p> {{ $question }} </p>
                    <div>Die Anzahl von Gruppen</div>
                    <p> {{ $group }} </p>
```

Comment: And can I just in one controller have many functions?

Comment: yes,you can add different function according to routes

Comment: Would you please mark the answer as correct answer? It helps others with similar problem. @Esoteriker